# Error at server shut down & start up org.apache.struts.upload.CommonsMultipartRequestHandler$CommonsFormFile

Tags: file-upload, stream, struts-1, nonserializedattribute

I am on a Struts 1 application!

My application show error when ever its Shut down & start up. I find two different but related error at both shut & start of my server.

The shut down error goes like below

```
WARNING: Cannot serialize session attribute EmailToClient for session C3E8630B365EE27FD5CE6AC6860D4BA8
java.io.NotSerializableException: org.apache.struts.upload.CommonsMultipartRequestHandler$CommonsFormFile
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSession.writeObject(StandardSession.java:1585)
    at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSession.writeObjectData(StandardSession.java:1015)
    at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardManager.doUnload(StandardManager.java:528)
    at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardManager.unload(StandardManager.java:469)
    at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardManager.stop(StandardManager.java:678)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.stop(StandardContext.java:4882)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.reload(StandardContext.java:3454)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappLoader.backgroundProcess(WebappLoader.java:426)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.backgroundProcess(ContainerBase.java:1361)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1653)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1662)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1662)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.run(ContainerBase.java:1642)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

And starting up the server back :

```
SEVERE: IOException while loading persisted sessions: java.io.WriteAbortedException: writing aborted; java.io.NotSerializableException: org.apache.struts.upload.CommonsMultipartRequestHandler$CommonsFormFile
java.io.WriteAbortedException: writing aborted; java.io.NotSerializableException: org.apache.struts.upload.CommonsMultipartRequestHandler$CommonsFormFile
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSession.readObject(StandardSession.java:1509)
    at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSession.readObjectData(StandardSession.java:998)
    at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardManager.doLoad(StandardManager.java:394)
    at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardManager.load(StandardManager.java:321)
    at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardManager.start(StandardManager.java:648)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4714)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.reload(StandardContext.java:3461)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappLoader.backgroundProcess(WebappLoader.java:426)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.backgroundProcess(ContainerBase.java:1361)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1653)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1662)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1662)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.run(ContainerBase.java:1642)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: org.apache.struts.upload.CommonsMultipartRequestHandler$CommonsFormFile
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSession.writeObject(StandardSession.java:1585)
    at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSession.writeObjectData(StandardSession.java:1015)
    at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardManager.doUnload(StandardManager.java:528)
    at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardManager.unload(StandardManager.java:469)
    at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardManager.stop(StandardManager.java:678)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.stop(StandardContext.java:4882)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.reload(StandardContext.java:3454)
    ... 7 more
May 2, 2013 4:43:52 PM org.apache.catalina.session.StandardManager start
SEVERE: Exception loading sessions from persistent storage
java.io.WriteAbortedException: writing aborted; java.io.NotSerializableException: org.apache.struts.upload.CommonsMultipartRequestHandler$CommonsFormFile
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSession.readObject(StandardSession.java:1509)
    at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSession.readObjectData(StandardSession.java:998)
    at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardManager.doLoad(StandardManager.java:394)
    at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardManager.load(StandardManager.java:321)
    at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardManager.start(StandardManager.java:648)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4714)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.reload(StandardContext.java:3461)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappLoader.backgroundProcess(WebappLoader.java:426)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.backgroundProcess(ContainerBase.java:1361)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1653)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1662)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1662)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.run(ContainerBase.java:1642)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: org.apache.struts.upload.CommonsMultipartRequestHandler$CommonsFormFile
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSession.writeObject(StandardSession.java:1585)
    at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSession.writeObjectData(StandardSession.java:1015)
    at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardManager.doUnload(StandardManager.java:528)
    at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardManager.unload(StandardManager.java:469)
    at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardManager.stop(StandardManager.java:678)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.stop(StandardContext.java:4882)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.reload(StandardContext.java:3454)
    ... 7 more
```

This error occurs when ever `EmailToClient`  action is been accessed. i.e.., Accessed the `EmailToClient`  , then shut down server error occured , followed with the error at start up .

`EmailToClient` is name of the form & action name in my struts application

Can Someone please help me. 
I wish some one can analyze the error & predict what  went wrong.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have persistent sessions, and your `EmailToClient` is in the session, but not serializable. If you want it serialized with the rest of your session, make it serializable.

Comment: Hai Dave,
EmailToClient is ActionForm & i suppose all ActionForm are serializable. please correct if wrong !

Comment: @deepuginde I think the issue is the file field. You might be able to get around it by making it non-serializable, but I'd need to check.